# Return object through 3 lists and one object

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net, sqldatareader

I have a query that gives me a Quiz with a Category, with a question and an answer, as you can see in the query below. However, I want to only use one reader, and I want it to be as object oriented as possible meaning I want Quiz to be the root object. Everything has to go through Quiz.

How can i return a quiz with a list of categories, with another list of questions and another list of answers?

Code below:

```
public Quiz GetQuizWithCategoriesWithQuestionsWithAnswers(int id)
    {
        Quiz quiz = null;
        Category category = null;
        Question question = null;
        Answer answer = null;
        dbConnection.connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = dbConnection.connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT Quiz.name, Category.name AS catName, Category.id as CatId, Category.quizId, Question.[description] as questDesc, Answer.[description] as ansDesc FROM Quiz JOIN Category ON Category.quizId = Quiz.id JOIN Question ON Question.categoryId = Category.id JOIN Answer ON Answer.questionId = Question.id WHERE Quiz.id = @id";
            command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (quiz == null)
                {
                    quiz = new Quiz();
                    quiz.name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("name"));
                    quiz.id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("quizId"));
                }
                if (category != null)
                {
                    if (category.id != reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("CatId")))
                    {
                        category = new Category();
                        category.id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("CatId"));
                        category.name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("catName"));
                        quiz.categories.Add(category);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    category = new Category();
                    category.id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("CatId"));
                    category.name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("catName"));
                    quiz.categories.Add(category);
                }
                if (question != null)
                {
                    //You'll need to get the question ID or just use the description here instead for comparison
                    if (question.description != reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("questDesc")))
                    {
                        question = new Question();
                        question.description = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("questDesc"));
                        category.question.Add(question);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    question = new Question();
                    question.description = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("questDesc"));
                    category.question.Add(question);
                }

                answer = new Answer();
                answer.description = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ansDesc"));
                question.Answers.Add(answer);
            }
        }
        dbConnection.connection.Close();
        return quiz;
    }

 public class Quiz
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<Category> categories { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<Player> players { get; set; }

        public Quiz()
        {
            categories = new List<Category>();
        }
    }

 public class Category
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int amount { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<Quiz> quiz { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<Question> question { get; set; }

        public Category()
        { 
            question = new List<Question>();
        }
    }

    public class Question
        {

            [DataMember]
            public int id { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string description { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public Category category { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public bool isAnswered { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }

            public Question()
            {
                Answers = new List<Answer>();
            }
        }

    public class Answer
        {
            [DataMember]
            public int id { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string description { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public Question question { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public bool isCorrect { get; set; }

        }
```

Comment: You have to detect the moment when the ID's changes, then you know that your "sub-object" is a new one and you have to add the last to the list.

Comment: Can you please elaborate in code as an example perhaps? I cant quite visualize what your'e trying to say.

Comment: The problem is that right now, im getting 1 quiz, with 1 category, with 1 question, with 1 answer, I need the whole list of questions and a the whole list of answers that are on the category ID

Comment: Your query should return a sinlge quiz, the problem is that you are overwriting the values in each iteration. I would probably create a stored procedure that will return the results in multiple select statements and then use the datareader's `NextResult()` method to get the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're problem is that you're loosing the values because you're re-declaring the Quiz object every time in the while loop, so it's loosing all it's previous values (the lists). You need to get the base values for the Quiz object outside the while loop (in another query and it's own loop) and separate queries for each list (to avoid duplicates in the joins)

**Edit:**

Or just check if the quiz object is instantiated and if new objects need to be created for categories and questions:

```
using (SqlCommand command = dbConnection.connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "SELECT Quiz.name, QuizCategory.quizId, QuizCategory.categoryId, Category.name AS catName, Question.[description], Answer.[description] FROM Quiz JOIN QuizCategory ON QuizCategory.quizId = Quiz.id JOIN Category ON Category.id = QuizCategory.categoryId JOIN Question ON Question.categoryId = Category.id JOIN Answer ON Answer.questionId = Question.id WHERE Quiz.id = @id";
                command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if(quiz==null)
                    {
                        quiz = new Quiz();
                        quiz.name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("name"));
                        quiz.id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("quizId"));
                    }

                    if(question!=null)
                    {
                        //You'll need to get the question ID or just use the description here instead for comparison
                        if(question.id!=reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("questionId"))
                        {
                            category.question.Add(question);
                            question = new Question();
                            question.description = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("description"));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        question = new Question();
                        question.description = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("description"));
                    }                        

                    if(category!=null)
                    {
                        if(category.id!=reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("categoryId"))
                        {
                            quiz.categories.Add(category);
                            category = new Category();
                            category.id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("categoryId"));
                            category.name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("catName"));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        category = new Category();
                        category.id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("categoryId"));
                        category.name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("catName"));
                    }

                    answer = new Answer();
                    answer.description = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("description"));
                    question.Answers.Add(answer);

                }
            }
            if(question!=null)
            {
                category.question.Add(question);
            }
            if(category!=null)
            {
                quiz.categories.Add(category);
            }
```

Comment: Is that really necessary? You cant have 1 big query that gets it all?

Comment: By the way, the query works 100% as intended in management studio

Comment: @Kingkong yes the query on it's own is perfect but the problem is that for each row you're discarding the entire object and making a new Quiz object so to optimize it for the code you need to split it. If you really want to put it in the same while loop and query just declare Quiz object outside the loop and set it equal to null. Check if it's null and create a new Quiz object if it's null.

Comment: Hang on, Ive edited something, let me show you in a second

Comment: That solves the question for quiz, but my category only has 1 question and 1 answer, I want 1 question to have a list of answers

Comment: @Kingkong you'll need to check if the category is a new category each time otherwise don't add or instantiate it and so forth for each list. I'll post the code now

Comment: @Kingkong I've updated my answer. You can change the question id check to description if the description value will be unique

Comment: Allright im testing it as we speak, Ill get back to you

Comment: @Kingkong oops I made a mistake. The add should be in the if blocks. Edited code to rectify mistake.

Comment: Its so close, Im only missing all the questions now, everything else is perfect, I edited my code above if you would please just take one last look, I get 1 question per category instead of all questions for 1 category

Comment: @Kingkong Ah I see my mistake. The code should only add the category when it's done and has all the questions. Changed the code, now the category is only added when a new one is found and at the end of the whole loop.

Comment: The problem is, it only gets 1 question per category, but there are 4 questions in 1 category in the database

Comment: The exact problem is as soon as it hits the if (question != null), second time, it just jumps over it, and doesnt create a new question object

Comment: @Kingkong okay I just updated the code, try this please.

Comment: That didnt work either, Ive updated the code, as it is now, I get all categories, every category has 1 question every question has 4 answers. I just need a list of questions, thats all.. Its so close

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128348/discussion-between-crimsonsage-and-kingkong).